# How to compare existing numbers from a file with with a random number?

Tags: java, random, while-loop, compare

I'm doing an exercise where I have to make a 'Lotto game'.

I've generated 6 random numbers (`rand1`, `rand2`, `rand3`, `rand4`, `rand5`, `rand6`), and now I have to compare them with my existing numbers, which is saved in a file `f`. I want to compare each random number at a time with the numbers I have saved in my file.

This is what I got so far:

```
public class lottoEx{

   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

      userNumbers(4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 19);

      drawNumbers();


   }

   public static void userNumbers(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4, int num5, int num6)throws Exception{ //USER NUMBERS

      File f = new File("lotto.dat");

      PrintStream output = new PrintStream(f);

      output.println(num1 + " " + num2 + " " +  num3 + " " + num4 + " " + num5 + " " + num6);

      Scanner read = new Scanner(f);

      System.out.print("Your numbers: ");

      while(read.hasNext()){

         System.out.print(read.nextInt() + " ");

      }

   }

   public static void drawNumbers()throws Exception{ //RANDOM NUMBERS

      Random rand = new Random();

      int rand1 = rand.nextInt(19)+1;
      int rand2 = rand.nextInt(19)+1;
      int rand3 = rand.nextInt(19)+1;
      int rand4 = rand.nextInt(19)+1;
      int rand5 = rand.nextInt(19)+1;
      int rand6 = rand.nextInt(19)+1;

      Thread.sleep(2000);

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("The lotto numbers are: ");

      Thread.sleep(2000);

      System.out.print(rand1 + " " + rand2 + " " + rand3 + " " + rand4 + " " + rand5 + " " + rand6);

         doCompare(rand1, rand2, rand3, rand4, rand5, rand6);

         winCheck();

   }

   public static void doCompare(int rand1, int rand2, int rand3, int rand4, int rand5, int rand6)throws Exception{

      Scanner scan = new Scanner("lotto.dat");

      Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

      while(scan.hasNextInt()){
         set.add(scan.nextInt());    
      }
      System.out.println(set);

      if(set.contains(rand1)){

         System.out.println("Match on rand1");

      }

   }

   public static void winCheck()throws Exception{

      //code goes here

   }

}
```

It seems like somethings wrong since it only compares the random number with the first number in my file? Im kind of stuck right now. Hope someone can help me out! :-)

Comment: It only contains 6 numbers:
4 10 7 5 11 19

Comment: You should consider using an array to store your values.

Comment: Side note : You don't have to use `BufferedReader+ FileReader` as argument to the scanner.. You can just pass the fileName.

Comment: only seperated with a space

Comment: @user3703289 - Directly use - `new Scanner(fileName)` and try..

Comment: I'm using bufferedReader + FileReader since this is inside a new method

Comment: @user3703289 - What difference does a `new method` make?

Comment: Your numbers: 4 10 7 5 11 19 

The lotto numbers are: 7 1 9 11 2 17

I runned it by adding the file name directly to scanner and got this output. Rand1 is 7 which matches one of my numbers. but still it doesn't come out with the print"MATCH"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and an efficient way is to store all the numbers in the file in a `Set`, and then look up the set for each random number. This way you only have to read the file once.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
    set.add(scan.nextInt());
}

if (set.contains(rand1)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH on rand1: " + rand1);
}

// repeat for rand2, rand3..etc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see the idea behind this method but! It still doesn't come out with the "Match found" even tho i get the numbers in my console: 

Your numbers: 4 5 7 9 11 19 

The lotto numbers are: 7 10 4 7 2 6

Can this has something to do with my methods the rand numbs come from? 

The method is called like this:
doCompare(rand1, rand2, rand3, rand4, rand5, rand6);

And this is how I start my method:
public static void doCompare(int rand1, int rand2, int rand3, int rand4, int rand5, int rand6)

Comment: Perhaps the file is not read correctly. After the while loop, try to see the content of the set. You can debug or print out the content.

Comment: Also, maybe you should update the question with the full code, including the calling method.

Comment: So now I have updated my questions with the full code. As u can see, I print the set but the output is just "[]". Somehow it doesnt fill in the number from lotto.dat?

Comment: First change the scanner to `new Scanner(new File("lotto.dat"))`. Second, from the method `drawNumbers()`, you're calling `doCompare()` with random numbers that change every time you run the program. Sometimes you'll have 0 matches, sometimes you'll have one or more matches. And what's the use of `userNumbers()`?

Comment: Changing the scanner to new Scanner(new File("lotto.dat")); works! Now the set list is filled with my own lotto numbers and ready to be compared. As said it's an exercise, and therfor it's neccessary to draw new rand numbs everytime :) I wopuld like to thank you a lot, I can now continue my work :) Thanks for your time! Edit: the use of userNumbers is because we had to make a method with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here an attempt using a [java.util.Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for storing the generated numbers and using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) constructor, which takes a File as argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final Set<Integer> lottoResults = new HashSet<>();
    final Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // generate numbers
    while (lottoResults.size() < 6) {
        lottoResults.add(rnd.nextInt(49) + 1);
    }

    final Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("path\\to\\yourLottoFile.txt"));
    for (String s : in.nextLine().split(",")) {
        final int lottoGuess = Integer.parseInt(s);
        // maybe some error handling here (invalid / wrong input)?

        System.out.printf("The guess: %2d is %s\n", lottoGuess, (lottoResults.contains(lottoGuess) ? "correct!!!" : "incorrect"));
    }
}
```

An example output would look like this:

```
The guess:  4 is incorrect
The guess: 10 is incorrect
The guess:  7 is incorrect
The guess:  5 is incorrect
The guess: 11 is correct!!!
The guess: 19 is incorrect
```